# Take value and insert it into a data attribute

Tags: jquery

How can I take the number that's in `.total-percent` and insert it into `aria-valuenow` using Jquery?

```
<div class="progress" role="progressbar" tabindex="0" aria-valuenow="" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
  <span class="progress-meter" style="width: 25%">
    <p class="progress-meter-text"><span class="total-percent-container">% complete</span></p>
  </span>
</div>
```

I currently have this Jquery that's taking the value and inserting it somewhere else but that's just a simple div, how can I do it with a data attribute?

```
<script>
jQuery(function($) {

    $(document).ready(function() {      

        // Move project timescales and completion to top of page
        $('.total-percent').contents().prependTo('.total-percent-container');

    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Are you expecting this to happen once on load, or every time the progress bar is updated? If the former, you can easily select the element then set the `attr()` of the relevant parent. If the latter, you'll need to hook to the progress update event of the bar.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Just once on load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have data attributes in your code. You can update `aria-valuenow` By using `.attr()`:

```
var currentProgress = $('.total-percent').text();
$('.progress').attr('aria-valuenow',currentProgress);
```

Also note that, it wont be changing the width of bar just by setting value above(as progress bar is already rendered). you need to modify width using css for that.

```
$('.progress-meter').css('width',currentProgress);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to change the attribute:

```
$('.progress').attr("aria-valuenow", "321"); //change the attribute to 321.
```